# Sql Query to fetch highest marks

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table structure is like this:

- `Student` (StudentID int, StudentName varchar(20))
- `Subject` (SubjectID int, SubjectName varchar(20))
- `Score` (ScoreID int, StudentID int, SubjectID int, Score int)

Here's the data

```
Student
| StudentID | StudentName |
|    1      |    John     |
|    2      |    Nash     |
|    3      |    Albert   |
---------------------------

Subject
| SubjectID | SubjectName |
|    1      |    Maths    |
|    2      |    Physics  |
|    3      |    Chemistry|
|    4      |    English  |
---------------------------

Score
| ScoreID | StudentID | SubjectID | Score |  
|     1   |     1     |     1     |   34  |
|     2   |     1     |     2     |   45  |
|     3   |     1     |     3     |   56  |
|     4   |     2     |     1     |   78  |
|     5   |     2     |     3     |   23  |
|     6   |     2     |     4     |   44  |
|     7   |     3     |     1     |   45  |
|     8   |     3     |     2     |   10  |
|     9   |     3     |     3     |   54  |
|    10   |     3     |     4     |   74  |
-------------------------------------------

Output:
|StudentName | Score | SubjectName |
|  John      |   45  |   Physics   |
|  John      |   56  |   Chemistry |
|  Nash      |   78  |   Maths     |
|  Albert    |   74  |   English   |
------------------------------------
```

I want to write a query to fetch the top scorer of every subject along with their scores and subject names, without using Row_Number(), Rank() and Dense_Rank().

I've written this query, but I think it can be improved:

```
select
    st.StudentName, Score, B.SubjectID
from 
    (select
         StudentID, Sc.SubjectID, Sc.Score
     from 
         (select
              SubjectID, MAX(Score) as 'Score'
          from 
              Score Sc
          inner join 
              subject sb on sc.subjectid = sb.subjectid
          group by 
              SubjectID) A
     inner join
         score sc on sc.SubjectID = a.SubjectID and sc.Score = A.Score) B
inner join 
    Student st on st.studentID = B.StudentID
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results are almost always helpful.

Comment: Pls read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: What behavior do you want in the event of ties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution without using RANK or ROW_NUMBER. Also this is much simplified to meet your output. Hope it helps

```
SELECT st.StudentName ,s.Score ,su.SubjectName  FROM (SELECT
SubjectID,MAX(Score) as Max   FROM Score GROUP BY SubjectID) a
INNER JOIN Score s  on a.SubjectID=s.SubjectID AND a.MAX=s.Score
INNER JOIN Student st on s.StudentID=st.StudentID 
INNER JOIN Subject su on s.SubjectID=su.SubjectID
```

Comment: NOTE: This Query does not breaks Ties, and would return all top scores!

Answer (score 1):

You would use the ANSI standard `rank()` or `row_number()` functions.  Assuming you want all duplicates, use `rank()`:

```
select StudentName, SubjectName, Score
from (select st.StudentName, su.SubjectName, s.Score,
             rank() over (partition by su.SubjectName order by s.Score desc) as seqnum
      from score s join
           student st
           on s.studentid = st.studentid join
           subject su
           on s.subjectid = su.subjectid 
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you wanted exactly one row per subject with an arbitrary top student, use `row_number()`.

In SQL Server, you can also do this without a subquery:

```
select top (1) with ties st.StudentName, su.SubjectName, s.Score
from score s join
     student st
     on s.studentid = st.studentid join
     subject su
     on s.subjectid = su.subjectid 
order by rank() over (partition by su.SubjectName order by s.Score desc)
```

Another fun option is `apply` -- and this doesn't use window functions and can have quite good performance:

```
select ss.StudentName, su.SubjectName, ss.Score
from subject su cross apply
     (select top (1) with ties s.*
      from score s join
           student st
           on s.studentid = st.studentid join
      where s.subjectid = su.subjectid 
      order by su.score desc
     ) ss;
```

Comment: Hi Gordan. Thanks for your help.
But your query is fetching NULL instead of the name Albert.
Let me know if I couldn't clarify my question!

Also, is there anyway to do this without using functions like Row_Number() and Rank().
Something using Group By and Max()

Comment: @Anshul . . . I don't see how this could be returning `NULL` for a student name if (1) all `score.studentid` are valid and (2) if no student names are `NULL`.  Both conditions seem true of your sample data.  Can you set up a SQL fiddle, db Fiddle, or rextester?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` like below

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT st.StudentName, sub.SubjectName, s.Score,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by sub.SubjectName order by s.Score Desc) as row_no
    FROM Score s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Student st on s.StudentID = st.StudentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Subject sub on s.SubjectID = sub.SubjectID) as tblMain
WHERE row_no = 1
```

Comment: Hello Hasan. Thanks for your help, but your query is not fetching appropriate result. Can you please look into the expected output above?